# How do I get a Japanese 6D to display more than 3 menu language options?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, canon-6d, international-differences

There are only three menu languages to choose from (English, Japanese and probably Chinese) in the settings of my 6D (bought in Japan). The information i found on [Which languages can be displayed? (EOS 6D)](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/8201707000.html) states that there should be 25 languages to choose from. How do I get to select the missing ones? Or is the firmware somehow different being that the camera was bought in Japan?

Comment: What firmware version is your 6D currently running?

Comment: @MichaelClark It's firmware 1.1.3

Comment: Is your camera the 6d (N) version that does not include Wi-Fi and GPS built in?

Comment: @MichaelClark No, it's the regular WiFi and GPS blessed kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently around 2009 or so Canon began making all models they sell in Japan with only two or three language options in an attempt to discourage grey market purchasers. Even if another firmware version is released, you will still only be able to select from the languages originally included in your camera's menu.

One purchaser from Australia mentioned on a [discussion board](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/51980878) that the local Canon Service Center said it would require a main board replacement to enable the full range of languages included in the cameras intended for US and Europe. Cameras sold in other Asian countries, such as India and Hong Kong, also have a different list of languages stored in the camera's main board, according to [this discussion](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=831140).

Answer (score 1):

The menu languages in cameras for asia region is factory locked.
You can unlock all languages using Canon Service Software - Tornado EOS

[Tornado EOS website](https://tornadosw.com/)

[Tornado EOS YouTube](https://youtu.be/b_N8N3e0A-A)

Comment: Hi Mike and welcome to Photo.SE. Could you please elaborate on how one can unlock languages using the Tornado EOS software? The Tornado EOS site does not have any docomenation. Your answer at the moment is not very useful.
Secondly, if you're affiliated with the software company in any way, could you please mention that in your answer?

Comment: Just found in google in russian repair forum, ask a testdrive by email and got it. Unlock is very easy - start software - click connect - click set language lock on features tab. Thats all, and free for short period like i understand. My 5D Mark III is unlocked.

Comment: I'm not affilated with company but they ask to wrote some feedback for free test drive if i want. So i do it.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your answer to show the steps with screenshots and mention that you got the software for free?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with Tornado EOS. I removed the language restriction from my 6D with Tornado EOS.

If you are familiar with programming you can also do it yourself. I don't know for 6D, but for 550D the property variable to change is 0x01000012. 0=JapanLimited, -1=NoRestriction.